# Error when creating table using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i'm new to postgresql i tried to create the following database but i keep getting this error when creating the table "HOTEL" :ERROR:  syntax error at or near "position"
LINE 4:                     positions position,
and i would like also to know how to querying this table ,thanks.

```
create type adresse as (
                    numRue INTEGER,
                    NomRue VARCHAR(30),
                    Ville  VARCHAR(30));

create type position as(
                    latitude REAL ,
                    longitude REAL);


create type chambre as(
                   numChambre INTEGER ,
                   typeChambre VARCHAR(30),
                   prix REAL);


create table hotel (
                nom VARCHAR(30),
                Adresse adresse,
                positions position,
                Chambres chambre,
                nbPersonnel INTEGER,
                nbEtoile INTEGER,
                telephone VARCHAR(14));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position` is a reserved keyword, if you want to use it, you have to use double quotes:

```
create table hotel 
(
  nom           varchar(30),
  adresse       adresse,
  positions     "position", --<< here
  chambres      chambre,
  nbpersonnel   integer,
  nbetoile      integer,
  telephone     varchar(14)
);
```

It would be better if you find a different name though.

Comment: that worked thanks a lot , and how can i accessing this data ?